# Table hiding in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am transferring data into a table all of sudden I went throgh a crazy problem I have never seen in my career.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Table_Report'.

Then I tried to create a table with same name and again I got fallowing error

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   There is already an object named 'Table_Report' in the database.

What went wrong I need to send data in to table asap but I am unable to do that at least I can't delete the table

> Cannot drop the table 'Table_Report', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Note: I have admin rights on the database.

Can you guys look what went wrong??

Comment: It'd probably be easier to diagnose if we could see the code that provokes these errors.

Comment: Might be a view with that name. What does `select name, type_desc from sys.objects where name = 'Table_Report'` return?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I can't think, off hand, of a statement where you expected to have a table name, gave a view name instead, and would produce that first error. They should be mostly interchangeable. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `create table foo (..)` will return with the error "there is already an object named 'foo'" if a view with the name `foo` exists. Although it will give a different error when trying to drop it...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name-iam getting USER_TABLE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, it could easily cause errors 2 and 3, but I can't think of a way it could cause error 1.

Comment: @all --Hey i got the answer table has VIEW

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is right, it's just an object with the same name, but you need to look into sys.objects to see what kind of objects it is so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue at work, what has probably happened is that someone created a table called Table_report under their username (instead of as the DBO - Database Owner). You should try:

```
Drop Table Table_report
```

Then rerun  your query.

EDIT: You should be able to run the following query to find all the existing tables in the database and find out which username is attached to the table

```
select ss.name ,st.* from sys.tables st
inner join sys.schemas ss
 on ss.schema_id = st.schema_id
```

Comment: if the table would contain data you would really have a problem wouldn't you?

Comment: NOTE. Cannot drop the table 'Table_Report', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: I found two of my own junk tables in the database with the above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Schema_name(schema_id) from sys.tables where name ='Table_report';
```

which schema is the result? 
If you want to move it do that:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo
TRANSFER SchemaSource.Table_report;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is nearly a decade old but, hopefully, it'll help other people that land on it during a search.

Table_Report could be ANY type of object.  Do a search on sys.objects (to start with).  This will also return the Schema Name if there's an object named 'Table_Report' and the 'type_desc' column will let you know what the object type is.  Of course, the code needs to be executed in the database you want to search in.

```
 SELECT SchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)
        ,*
   FROM sys.objects
  WHERE name = 'Table_Report'
;
```

I also agree with what @GBoehm stated in a comment on this thread.  Don't drop any objects until you're sure your not going to make someone else's stuff go haywire.  You don't want your work to become a resume generating event. :D