# Getting error when transfering custom schema to dbo

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, alter

I wanted to change one of table's schema to the dbo

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER Member.Adress;
```

But I get this error.

> Msg 15530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object with name "Adress" already exists.

This doesn't make sense, when I create new custom schema I can transfer same table under the new schema without problem but when I try to transfer it to **dbo**, I get this error.

Comment: Are you sure the Address table isn't already in the dbo schema?

Comment: Yes I am certainly sure.

Comment: But it's not Address though, it's Adress. Maybe check that.

Comment: @kcung I've got only one `Adress` table which is under the `Member` schema right now. Yes, the name of the table should be `Address`, I'll fix that. But the problem is not because of that.

Comment: Ok, cool. If that's the case, have you tried to do "select * from dbo.Adress" ? If not, this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659426/table-hiding-in-sql-server-database

Comment: Yes I tried  `select * from dbo.Adress` and I get this error `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.Adress'.` 
I also checked the link which you sent to me and then run this query also `select ss.name ,st.* from sys.tables st
inner join sys.schemas ss
 on ss.schema_id = st.schema_id`  . `Adress` table is under the `Member` schema in the result set as expected and there is no junk `Adress` table under the `dbo` schema.